# Next.js: SyntaxError: Named export 'i18n' not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next

How can I resolve the SyntaxError 'Named export 'i18n' not found' when importing a CommonJS module './next-i18next.config.js' in my project? The error suggests using default export, but how can I properly import and use named exports from this module?
**next.config.mjs:**

```
import { i18n } from "./next-i18next.config.js";
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};

module.exports = {
  i18n,
  nextConfig,
};
```

**next-i18next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next-i18next').UserConfig} */
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "de"],
  },
};
```